# How to use React Hook Form with Typescript (Input Component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

The component has no errors, but in the index file where I actually call the input component, it has an error because it cannot use register = {register}.

What is missing? Or what's wrong?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-typescript-xnb1u

Comment: I found an article that helped me find the solution.

Codebox has the right solution for those who want to use typescript componentization using React Hook Form.

Answer (score 11):

OK here the problems:

1. you need to add `register` to props in the Input component props declaration
2. you must use the `register` passed as prop, not a new one created with `useForm` in Input component
3. the input element is missing the name attribute

here the working `<Input>` component with comments:

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import {
  FieldValues,
  UseFormRegister,
  // useForm, // don't need this import
} from "react-hook-form";

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>; // declare register props
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ id, label, register, ...rest }) => {
  //const { register } = useForm(); // don't use a new `register`, use the one from props

  return (
    <div className="input-block">
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <br />
      <br />
      
      {/* react-hook-form v6 */}
      {/* you must declare the `name` attribute on the input element */}
      <input name={id} type="text" id={id} ref={register} {...rest} />

      {/* react-hook-form v7 */}
      {/* In v7 the register() function returns all the needed properties */}
      {/* see: https://dev.to/bluebill1049/what-s-coming-in-react-hook-form-version-7-4bfa */}
      {/* <input type="text" id={id} {...register(id)} {...rest} /> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: FYI, the `register` prop is actually of type `UseFormRegister<FieldValues>`.

Comment: `register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;` this is the expected type. You can import them as `import { FieldValues, UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";`

Comment: any solution for react-hook-for v7 ?

Comment: Apparently you just need to replace the `ref={register}` with `{...register(id)}` (and remove the `name` property) as in v7 `register('name')` provides all the needed props for the input element, see this post about v7 changes: https://dev.to/bluebill1049/what-s-coming-in-react-hook-form-version-7-4bfa

Comment: not working form me, I get this error `Type 'FieldValues' is missing the following properties from type` and then it lists all my form fields

Comment: I have the same issue as Luiz. And the answer with another example from stackoverflow is a bit different and comes with another error.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article that helped me find the solution.

Codebox has the right solution for those who want to use typescript componentization using React Hook Form.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-typescript-xnb1u

Answer (score 1):

In this case `register` prop should be something that **extends** `FieldValues` not be a `FieldValues`

There is a complete example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77636341/1633344