# What type to use for register from the react-hook-form register typescript type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use `react-hook-form` to control my custom input fields but I'm stuck on the type for the `register` property in my custom component.

**Login.tsx**

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { loginValidationSchema } from '../../validators/auth';
import TextField from '../../components/formElements/TextField';
import PasswordField from '../../components/formElements/PasswordField';
import Button from '../../components/buttons/Button';

type FormValues = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
};

const Login = () => {
    const {
        register: LoginRegister,
        handleSubmit: handleLoginSubmit,
    } = useForm<FormValues>({ resolver: yupResolver(loginValidationSchema) });

    const onLoginSubmitHandler = (values: FormValues) => {
        console.log(values);
    };

    return (
        <div className="w-full max-w-lg space-y-8">
            <form onSubmit={handleLoginSubmit(onLoginSubmitHandler)} className="space-y-8">
                <fieldset className="space-y-6">
                    <TextField
                        label="pages.login.login_form.email.label"
                        placeholder="pages.login.login_form.email.placeholder"
                        name="email"
                        register={LoginRegister}
                    />

                    <PasswordField
                        label="pages.login.login_form.password.label"
                        placeholder="pages.login.login_form.password.placeholder"
                        name="password"
                        register={LoginRegister}
                    />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <Button type="submit" label="pages.login.login_form.submit" width="full" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

**TextField.tsx**

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { FieldError } from 'react-hook-form';
import Input from './common/Input';
import Error from './common/Error';
import Label from './common/Label';

interface TextFieldProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    label?: string;
    name: string;
    register: any; // Type?
    placeholder?: string;
    error?: FieldError;
}

const TextField = ({ label, name, register, placeholder = '', error }: TextFieldProps) => {
    return (
        <div className="space-y-2">
            <Label label={label} name={name} />
            <Input type="text" name={name} register={register} placeholder={placeholder} />
            <Error error={error} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default TextField;
```

**Input.tsx**

```
import { HTMLInputTypeAttribute } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

type InputProps = {
    type: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
    name: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    register: any;
};

const Input = ({ type, name, placeholder = '', register }: InputProps) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return <input type={type} placeholder={t(placeholder)} {...register(name)} />;
};

export default Input;
```

`register` has a type of `any` right now. Different topics are saying to use `UseFormRegister<FieldValues>` coming from the `react-hook-form` package as type: `register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>;` but this results in an `register`-error on the Login page:

```
Type 'UseFormRegister<FormValues>' is not assignable to type 'UseFormRegister<FieldValues>'.
  Type 'FieldValues' is missing the following properties from type 'FormValues': email, passwordts(2322)
TextField.tsx(10, 5): The expected type comes from property 'register' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldProps'
```

I could not found an example or working solution in the official Typescript docs of `react-hook-form` nor on this platform. I'm using V7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `InputProps` a generics type of something that extends `FieldValues`, with that you can make your register a `UseFormRegister` type of your T and change your name to be a `Path` type of your `<T>` (instead of a string)

```
type InputProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
    type: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
    name: Path<T>;
    placeholder?: string;
    register: UseFormRegister<T>;
};
```

In your component, you need to do the same

```
const Input = <T extends FieldValues>({ register }: InputProps<T>) => {
    return <input type={type} placeholder={t(placeholder)} {...register(name)} />;
};
```

Comment: Whoever wants to make register optional in your custom component and are unsure how to use spreading in the HTML input, that's the syntax I used: `{...(register ? register(name) : {})}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to substitute `FieldValues` for something at least as specific as the type you used in your `useForm` call. In your case `UseFormRegister<FormValues>` is the easiest.

Comment: That's what I tried (see last lines below the `Input` code) but is giving me an error

Comment: @Thore are you using that type in both places you pass `register`?

Comment: Yes, both PropTypes for TextField and PasswordField have `UseFormRegister<FormValues>` as register type. I can make a Sandbox if that would be easier to discuss/test things